# $p = x^2 + y^2$ where does proof limit cases it applies

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

This question concerns a proof from the book 'Proofs from the Book' Sixth Edition by M. Aigner and G. Ziegler.

The theorem and proof in question are on page 21 of my copy.

> Theorem: Every prime of the form $p = 4m + 1$ is a sum of two squares, i.e. can be written $p = x^2+y^2$ for some $x,y \in Z$

There are apparently many proofs to this but the proof I am looking at is where for any *s* we construct two non-identical $(x',y')$ and $(x'',y'')$ with both in $ \{0,1,...\lfloor \sqrt p \rfloor \} $ where $ x' - sy' \equiv x'' - sy'' $ *(mod p)*.

Then as you can show $\exists$s *such that* $s^2 \equiv -1$ *(mod p)* you take some differences, do some squares and bada boom you have $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0$ *(mod p)* and because both *x* and *y* are $< \sqrt p$ $x^2 + y^2 < 2p \implies x^2 + y^2 = p$

I realize somewhere in my 'broad strokes must be what I'm missing but I cannot see it and I cannot really reproduce the whole proof. It was credited to Axel Thue FYI.

What I want to know is, this proof seems to apply to *all p* but the theorem statement goes out of the way to restrict it to *p* of the form $p=4m+1$.

Indeed it is pretty trivial to prove independently that the above relationship does not hold for $p=4m+3$ which is pretty much all the other primes (except $p=2$).

But where in my proof do I break down if $p=4m+3$?

Thanks in advance for helping fill a gap for me. I really like this proof but this is a gap for me.

Comment: @calvin, indeed I did define that in the question, we only need to constrain that towards the end, all prior applies for all s

Comment: So sorry, you're correct! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to find an $s$ such that $ s^ 2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.
There is no such $s$ when $ p = 4k + 3$. (Can you show why?)

When $ p = 4k+1$, you can find such an $s$ by using $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.